# how to correctly bind a View control to a ViewModel List (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to bind a List to a UniformGrid into a WP Window using WPF MVVM.

I had in mind to do something like this:

Into my VM:

```
   private List<Rat> rats;
        private UniformGrid uniformGrid;
        public List<Rat> Rats
        {
            get { return rats; }
            set
            {

                if (rats != value)
                    {
                    //update local list value
                        rats = value;

                    //create View UniformGrid
                        if (uniformGrid == null)
                            uniformGrid = new UniformGrid() { Rows=10};
                        else
                            uniformGrid.Children.Clear();
                    foreach(Rat rat in value)
                    {
                        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(){Height=20, Width=20, Stroke= Brushes.Black};
                        if (rat.Sex== SexEnum.Female)
                            ellipse.Fill= Brushes.Pink;
                        else 
                             ellipse.Fill= Brushes.Blue;

                        stackPanel.Children.Add(ellipse  );
                        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
                        textBlock.Text= rat.Name + " (" + rat.Age +")";
                        stackPanel.Children.Add( textBlock  );
                        uniformGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
                    }


                        OnPropertyChanged("Rats");
                    }            
            }
        }
```

The VM is correctly informed when the list needs to be refreshed into the view via an event.
So at this point I would need my View to be correctly bound to the VM. I made it this way:

```
 <GroupBox x:Name="GB_Rats" Content="{Binding Rats}"  Header="Rats" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="194" Margin="29,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303">
```

Is this the correct global approch?

Concretely, when attempting to run the code, this line fails to execute:

```
 uniformGrid = new UniformGrid() { Rows=10};
```

->

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

This lets me think that I should not proceed this way from a MVVM point of view.

Thx for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewModel` isn't supposed to instantiate any UI controls, this should be the View's responsibility.

So in your code you shouldn't try to create `StackPanels`, `Ellipses` etc.

Also try to use the types that already have Change notification - for instead of 
`List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx), i wouldn't recommend replacing a whole list when its value change.

The right way to do this in the MVVM pattern is to create a `DataTemplate` for the `Rat` like this:

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Rat> Rats { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<Rat>()
        {
            new Rat()
            {
                Name = "Fred",
                Age = "19",
                Sex = SexEnum.Male
            },
            new Rat()
            {
                Name = "Martha",
                Age = "21",
                Sex = SexEnum.Female
            }
        };

}
```

Model - Rat and Sex:

```
public class Rat
{
    public SexEnum Sex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

public enum SexEnum
{
    Female,
    Male
}
```

As you want to present the Models value of Sex in one of two colors you should use a `IValueConverter` for that:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(SexEnum), typeof(Brush))]
public class SexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is SexEnum))
            throw new ArgumentException("value not of type StateValue");
        SexEnum sv = (SexEnum)value;
        //sanity checks
        if (sv == SexEnum.Female)
            return Brushes.Red;
        return Brushes.Blue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is then used in your window:

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:ViewModel="WpfApplication1.VM"
        xmlns:Converters ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Converters:SexToColorConverter x:Key="SexToBrushConverter"></Converters:SexToColorConverter>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Rats}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Sex, Converter={StaticResource SexToBrushConverter}}"></Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Age}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note the `DataTemplate` that is assigned to the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` property and the declaration of the `Converters:SexToColorConverter` and its usage to change the color of the ellipse in the `Fill` binding.

**Update 4.4.2016 16:30**
Window using a `GroupBox` with `CheckBoxes` to display the list

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:Converters ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.VM">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Converters:SexToColorConverter x:Key="SexToBrushConverter"></Converters:SexToColorConverter>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <GroupBox>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rats}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Margin="5"></CheckBox>
                            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Sex, Converter={StaticResource SexToBrushConverter}}"></Ellipse>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Age}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I guess the target is to also select the Rats, depending on how MVVM purist you want to be you'd add a List of `RatViewModels`, that have a bool IsChecked property and bind the `ItemsSource` to a `ObservableCollection<RatViewModel>` and synchronize this list with your Models `List<Rat>`

Comment: Brillant answer. Thanks a ton. Before I close the question, would you know how to stick to a Groupbox rather than switching to a ComboBox or ListBox?
I need to use a GroupBox to preserve the application's design. But GroupBox does not have any ItemsSource property, not UniformGrid.

Comment: Sorry missed the `GroupBox` 
- `GroupBox` is just a container not really meant for binding to, you should bind a custom amount of items to a `ItemControl` such as a `ComboBox`. There you have to edit the template to contain Checkboxes. What's the target you are pursuing there? Do you need to get the selected Rats afterwards?

Comment: It just workslike a charm, thanksa gain for your assistance.Earnedme a lot of time!