# programmatically bind button to double click command wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, behavior

I have the following `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SequencesFilesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SequencesFiles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="DarkBlue" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
```

The `SequencesFiles` defined as `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection<Button>`.

I'm manually adding new `Buttons` to the collections using the following function:

```
private void AddSequenceToPlaylist(string currentSequence)
{
    if (SequencesFiles.Any(currentFile => currentFile.ToolTip == currentSequence)) return; 

    var newSequence = new Button
    {
        ToolTip = currentSequence,
        Background = Brushes.Transparent,
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        Content = Path.GetFileName(currentSequence),
        Command = PlaylistLoadCommand,
        CommandParameter = currentSequence,
    };
    SequencesFiles.Add(newSequence);
}
```

Is it possible to call the `Command` (`PlaylistLoadCommand`) upon double-click and not upon click?

Comment: *I'm manually adding new Buttons to the collections...* Well, there's your problem.  You can probably achieve your goals in an easier way.  You might want to review *why* you are doing this, and perhaps ask for a better, more mvvm/wpf-ish way of accomplishing your goals.  In another question.

Comment: Can you up-vote my answer( badges and stuff)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `InputBinding` to your `Button` to fire your command on double click

```
var newSequence = new Button
{
    ToolTip = currentSequence,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    Content = Path.GetFileName(currentSequence),
    CommandParameter = currentSequence,
};

var mouseBinding = new MouseBinding();
mouseBinding.Gesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftDoubleClick);
mouseBinding.Command = PlaylistLoadCommand;
newSequence.InputBindings.Add(mouseBinding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in this question, I would advise against creating User Controls in your ViewModel : [how to correctly bind a View control to a ViewModel List (WPF MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391083/how-to-correctly-bind-a-view-control-to-a-viewmodel-list-wpf-mvvm/36392354#36392354)

For double click bindings, unfortunately it's still not supported in the WPF toolkit see this question: [How to bind a command in WPF to a double click event handler of a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293530/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf-to-a-double-click-event-handler-of-a-control)